# how to add a button inside header view of table view in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just want to add a button in the right side of headerview. I dont want to create a new headerview. How can we add button inside the existing header view?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the header view of the table by the following code.

```
UIView *headerView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
```

And you can add a button to this view.

Comment: I tried following code in viewdidload. but nothing happens     UIView *headerView = self.tblView.tableHeaderView;
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 0, 50, 30)];
    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [headerView addSubview:btn];

Comment: actInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    actInd.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, (SCRN_HEIGHT-120)/2, 10, 10);
    [self.view addSubview:actInd];
    [actInd startAnimating];
    
    tempImages = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    self.title = [[JsonModel sharedJsonModel] title];
    
    tblView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    tblView.rowHeight = 100;
    tblView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gradientBackground"];